# Rxjs conditional switchMap based on a condition

Tags: rxjs, conditional-statements, switchmap

I have a situation like the following:

```js
myObservable1.pipe(
  switchMap((result1: MyObservable1) => {
    if (condition) {
      return myObservable2;
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })
).subscribe(myObservable1 | myObservable2) => {
```

So if condition is false I only have to perform one request, if the condition is true, I have to chain the first request to the following one, they are essentially two requests to the server api.

Is there a better solution without returning that `null`?
Is there any conditional operator in RxJs?

Thanks!

Comment: you can return `empty()` observable

Comment: I tried, but it says: '[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Observer<any>' has no compatible call signatures.
'

Comment: Checkout this article that explains it all in depth: https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-patterns-conditionally-executing-work/

Answer (score 28):

Another possibility is to use the operator iif in a SwitchMap.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif

but it can restrain the possibility to control specfic 
conditions on your Observable :

```
myObservable1
.pipe( 
      switchMap(result1 =>
               iif(() => condition
               , myObservable2
               , myObservable1
            )
      )
.subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Where you can replace 'condition' by a function returning a boolean. 
With a function :

```
myObservable1
    .pipe( 
          switchMap(result1 =>
                   iif(() => test(result1)
                   , myObservable2
                   , myObservable1
                )
          )
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result)); 

test(result1) : boolean {
     if(result1){
       // the iif() will return myObservable2
       return true;
     }else{
       /: the iif() will return myObservable1
       return false ;
     }
}
```

Like @amjuhire said , you can write with a filter and a switchMap :

```
myObservable1.pipe(
  filter((result1) => condition)
  switchMap((result1: MyObservable1) => {
    return myObservable2;
  })
).subscribe(result2 => { ... })
```

Another possibility given your example :

```
myObservable1.pipe(
  switchMap((result1: MyObservable1) => {
    if (condition) {
      return myObservable2;
    } else {
      return of(result1);
    }
  })
subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Or using EMPTY in the switchMap :

```
 myObservable1.pipe(
      switchMap((result1: MyObservable1) => {
        if (condition) {
          return myObservable2;
        } else {
          // Observable that immediately completes
          return EMPTY;
        }
      })
    subscribe(result2 => console.log(result2));
```

The problem here is that we don't know the type in your observable.

So i can't judge wich way is the better.

It also depends on how you want to handle the success/error between the different calls of your observable.

Answer (score 18):

No need to return of(null), you should use the RxJs filter operator

```
myObservable1.pipe(
  filter((result1) => condition)
  switchMap((result1: MyObservable1) => {
    return myObservable2;
  })
).subscribe((result2) => { ... })
```

Answer (score 9):

In my understanding, you shouldn't use `filter` operator because in that case you wouldn't get any value.

```
myObservable1.pipe(
  switchMap((value) => {
    return iif(() => condition, myObservable2, of(value));
  })
).subscribe((value) => console.log(value) // either from myObservable1 or from myObservable2)
```

Comment: I think that your answer is valid. But i'm not sur if the question asked specifically to catch a value from the first observable. If the filter returns true, it will execute the switchMap, else the observable1 will still execute even if it won't return any value

Comment: @Koraxos You may be right but given OP's code: `subscribe(myObservable1 | myObservable2)`, I assumed he/she was going to do something with the value either from obs1 or from obs1 * obs2.

Comment: yes i understand that , and that's why i said that youy answer is valid , i agree with you on that point. And that's why i think, if the question was a little more detail, we would be able to find the best answer

Answer (score -1):

I don't know your real code, this is the pseudo code, and I don't know which rxjs version are you using now, but you can do something like below:

assuming you are using rxjs 6:

```
iif(condition, obervable1, concatMap(observable1, observable2))
.subscribe()
```