# Dependent nested observables

Tags: angular, observable, subscription

I have two methods in which I'm doing some asynchronous operation but I don't want method 2 to execute until or unless the response from method 1 is positive, to indicate that we can proceed further.

So, this is what I tried:

Method 1:

```
private method1(): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(() => {
    executingSomething();
    this.anotherSubscription.pipe(
      map(x => {
        console.log('Control is not reaching here');
        Also, how to indicate the caller that method2 can be executed?
        I can't return anything since I'm already returning the new Observable, above.
      })
    );
  });
}
```

Caller:

```
concat(this.method1(), this.method2()).subscribe();
```

Issue: `anotherSubscription` is not even getting executed and I can't think of any way to pass a response from within `anotherSubscription` to the caller.

I feel that I'm not using the observables in correct sense, here but can't seem to find anything anywhere.

Comment: This is also closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452947/rxjs-conditional-switchmap-based-on-a-condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some assumptions regarding your code prior to writing the solution. If the assumptions are wrong, then the answer may be as well.

1. `executingSomething()` is a *synchronous* method with unrelated functionality, except that you want the whole thing to fail if it throws.
2. `anotherSubscription` is not a `Subscribtion` but an `Observable` (these are different things).

Here's how I'd solve your problem:

```typescript
class SomeClass {
  private method1(): Observable<any> {
    try {
      executingSomething();
    } catch (err) {
      // This would return an errorred observable, which is great, since
      // you can still subscribe to it (no need to change the return type
      // of this method).
      return throwError(err);
    }

    return this.anotherSubscription.pipe(
      tap(() => {
        console.log('Controls is reaching here!');
      }),
    );
  }

  private method2(): Observable<any> {
    // This can be whatever obervable, using of(null) for demo purposes.
    return of(null);
  }

  private parentMethod() {
    this.method1()
      .pipe(
        switchMap(valueFromAnotherSubscription => {
          // UPD1 - Implement your custom check here. This check will determine
          // whether `method2` will be called.
          if (valueFromAnotherSubscription === targetValue) {
            return this.method2();
          } else {
            // UPD1 - If the check evaluates to `false`, reemit the same value
            // using the `of` operator.
            return of(valueFromAnotherSubscription);
          }
        }),
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Done!');
      });
  }
}
```

The key operator here, as correctly indicated by Kevin, is `switchMap`. Every time an observable (`anotherSubscription`) emits, `switchMap` will cancel it and subscribe to a different observable (whatever is returned from `method2`).

This happens sequentially so `method2` will only be subscribed to *after* `method1` emits. If `method1` throws, the whole pipeline will fail. You may also `filter` the results of `method1` to decide whether or not you want to switch to `method2`.

Also, constructing observables using `new Observable` is probably not needed in most cases. I have a rather large RxJS application and have never used this so far.

### Update 1

See code denoted with `UPD1` comments.

Keep in mind that **if an error is thrown by `anotherSubscription`**, the `switchMap` function **will not be called** anyway.

Comment: Any specific reason you used `tap` instead of `map` ?

Comment: Yes, `map`'s purpose is returning a different value for every emitted value. Conversely, `tap` is used for side-effects. I consider a `log` statement to be a side-effect, so `tap` is more appropriate. But you may do this inside a `map` statement as well - it will work, just don't forget to return your value : ]

Comment: One more thing. How do I filter my response from method1? In fact, how do I return something (such as a boolean to indicate whether to proceed further or not) when I'm returning `Observable<any>`? I tried returning `of(false)` but I can't use that `false` until I subscribe to it and I'd need to do it in `switchMap(res => { if (res) { } )`, else it would execute method2.

Comment: OK, so what's clear to me is that whenever `method1` emits the "correct" value, you want the subscriber to receive a value from `method2`. What's not clear is what should happen when `method1` emits a "bad" value. I see two possible scenarios, tell me which one you need: A) when `method1` emits a "bad" value, you want to completely ignore such values, so the subscriber is not alerted at all; B) when `method1` emits a "bad" value, you simply want the subscriber to receive that value, whilst skipping `method2`. I hope the difference is clear. I have updated the answer using option B.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at some wrong console output and got confused. Thank you for your help. This works.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly return the value of the serviceN to the serviceN+1. Here's the idea :

```
private setupStuff() {
  this.initRouteParams()
    .pipe(
      switchMap(serviceId => {
        return zip(of(serviceId), this.getFileInfo(serviceId))
      }),
      switchMap(([serviceId, filename]) => {
        return zip(of(serviceId), of(filename), this.getExistingFile(serviceId, filename))
      })
    )
    .subscribe(([serviceId, filename, response]) => {
      console.log(serviceId, filename, response);
    })
}
```

Comment: What I'm asking and what you're suggesting are completely different. I want to return some response from within an observable, which is nested within another observable. And on top of that, inner observable is not even getting executed.

Comment: Just write a single example, is this satisfy you requirement? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rn5kfe?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

> "I don't want method 2 to execute until or unless the response from
> method 1 is positive"

If you just want the emission from obs2, to be triggered after the emission of obs1 (no matter what obs1 emits), just use a switchMap:

```
fromEvent(document, 'click')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => of([1]))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log); <--- will emit [1] only after the user clicks.
```

If you need that obs2 only emits after obs1 emits a specific value, use switchMap with a filter operator (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter):

```
const obs$ = of(true); 
const obs2$ = of([1,2,3]);

    obs$.pipe(
        filter((result) => result === true),
        switchMap(() => obs2$)
      ).subscribe(console.log) <--- returns [1,2,3] since filter condition returns true
```

if you need something like an If Else statement, use the conditional operator IIF
(https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif):

```
const even$ = of('even');
const odd$ = of('odd');

interval(1000).pipe(
  mergeMap(v =>
    iif(
      () => v % 2 === 0,
      even$,
      odd$
    ))
).subscribe(console.log); <--- will emit every second a string "even" or "odd" based on the condition.
```